# How to extract an embedded assembly without the CLR failing to find it first?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, embed

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)  shows how to embed an assembly inside another. However, the extracted assembly will be extracted only if it is not found elsewhere. This raises a security concern - what if someone put an assembly with the same name as the embedded one - that other assembly would be used. How can one get around that, and extract the assembly without the CLR failing to find it first.

**EDIT** Yes. One can sign the assembly. But I'd still like to know if it can be done this way which looks like the *right* way.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This looks like you want to reinvent a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you say signing isn't the right way? The purpose of signing is authenticating the assembly and that seems to be your primary concern. If you don't sign the assembly, I could simply replace the assembly you have embedded with another one with the same name.

Anyway you could try to load the embedded assembly using reflection *before* your code attempts to reference it - by running the code currently in your `AssemblyResolve` explicitly on startup.

Comment: I tried loading the assembly at startup. It fails at `Application.Run(new Form1());` - `Could not load file or assembly '...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Is your assembly referencing other assemblies? Does the exception contain a `FusionLog` with more specific information?